How to calculate public key of same private key on two different ECDSA Curves?
I want to calculate the public key of the same private key on two ECDSA Curves? I need to get a valid public key for two (2) curves by using the public key one (1) curve.
I need to get a valid public key by using only the first curve of the  ECDSA public key and getting two (2) curves public key. Is it possible?
from sage.all import *

p = 625276251724681468065787127391468008213949163
K = GF(p)
a = K(1)
b = K(0)
E = EllipticCurve(K, (a, b))
G = E.gen(0)
order = G.order()

print('Curve 1')

print('Private Key 1:', G * 1)
print('Private Key 3:', G * 3)

p = 625276251724681468065787127391468008213949163
K = GF(p)
a = K(2)
b = K(0)
E = EllipticCurve(K, (a, b))
G = E.gen(0)
order = G.order()

print('Curve 2')

print('Private Key 1:', G * 1)
print('Private Key 3:', G * 3)

Updated code if you will run you will understand what I want to get
from sage.all import *

p = 625276251724681468065787127391468008213949163
K = GF(p)
a = K(1)
b = K(0)
E1 = EllipticCurve(K, (a, b))
G = E1.gen(0)
order = G.order()

print('Curve 1')

print('Private Key 1:', G * 1)
print('Private Key 2:', G * 2)
print('Private Key 3:', G * 3)
print('Private Key 4:', G * 4)

Q = G * 1

xPoint1 = Q[0]
yPoint1 = Q[1]

p = 625276251724681468065787127391468008213949163
K = GF(p)
a = K(2)
b = K(0)
E2 = EllipticCurve(K, (a, b))
G = E2.gen(0)
order = G.order()

print('Curve 2')

print('Private Key 1:', G * 1)
print('Private Key 2:', G * 2)
print('Private Key 3:', G * 3)
print('Private Key 4:', G * 4)

xPoint2 = xPoint1 ** 3 + E2.a4() * xPoint1 + E2.a6()

print(xPoint2)

print(str(int(xPoint2)) + ' point must be 219353496172135284783954733308447544042907454 how can I culculate and get that one?')

trialPublicKeys = E2.lift_x(xPoint2, all=True)

print(trialPublicKeys)


It's hard to understand what you're asking, perhaps you can clarify? My guess is that, given the public key pub1 = priv * G1, with priv unknown, you want to be able to compute pub2 = priv * G2, where G1 and G2 are known points from different elliptic curves. I'm not aware of any way to go from pub1 to pub2 without knowing priv.

Clarify if you want to derive public keys from a given private key on different curves or something else.

Yes for me priv key is unknown I want to calculate right public key with only using one curve for public key two curve.

I calculated x point by this   x_Point_1 ** 3 + Curve2.a4() * x_Point_1 + Curve2.a6()   and I got right public key but not same private key I want to derive same unknown private key public key.
